# Queueing collections with multiple model types is not supported

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have two tables in my database which are part of a same category, but need to be in different tables. I'm trying to make a monthly report, but I keep getting the error `Queueing collections with multiple model types is not supported` and I don't know what to do nor have I been able to find a solution.

Here's my function

```
public function ComprasPorFecha()
{

    if ($this->tipoReporte == 0) {
        $from = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now())->format('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00';
        $to = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now())->format('Y-m-d')   . ' 23:59:59';
    } else {
        $from = Carbon::parse($this->desde)->format('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00';
        $to = Carbon::parse($this->hasta)->format('Y-m-d')   . ' 23:59:59';
    }

    if ($this->tipoReporte == 1 && ($this->desde == '' || $this->hasta == '')) {
        $notas = Nentrega::join('users as u', 'u.id', 'nentregas.user_id')
            ->select('nentregas.*', 'u.name as user')
            ->whereBetween('nentregas.fecha_compra', [$from, $to])
            ->get();
    
        $facturas = Compra::join('users as u', 'u.id', 'compras.user_id')
            ->select('compras.*', 'u.name as user')
            ->whereBetween('compras.fecha_compra', [$from, $to])
            ->get();
    
            $c = $facturas->merge($notas)->sortByDesc('created_at');

        $this->data = $c;
        return $this->data;
    }
    if ($this->userId == 0) {
        $notas = Nentrega::join('users as u', 'u.id', 'nentregas.user_id')
            ->select('nentregas.*', 'u.name as user')
            ->whereBetween('nentregas.fecha_compra', [$from, $to])
            ->get();
    
        $facturas = Compra::join('users as u', 'u.id', 'compras.user_id')
            ->select('compras.*', 'u.name as user')
            ->whereBetween('compras.fecha_compra', [$from, $to])
            ->get();
    
            $c = $facturas->merge($notas)->sortByDesc('created_at');

            $this->data = $c;
    } else {
        $notas = Nentrega::join('users as u', 'u.id', 'nentregas.user_id')
            ->select('nentregas.*', 'u.name as user')
            ->whereBetween('nentregas.fecha_compra', [$from, $to])
            ->where('user_id', $this->userId)
            ->get();
    
        $facturas = Compra::join('users as u', 'u.id', 'compras.user_id')
            ->select('compras.*', 'u.name as user')
            ->whereBetween('compras.fecha_compra', [$from, $to])
            ->where('user_id', $this->userId)
            ->get();
    
            $c = $facturas->merge($notas)->sortByDesc('created_at');

        $this->data = $c;
    }

}
```

I read that models should have `protected $connection = "mysql";` so they both do. I need to search the records on both tables, is there a way around this error?

Comment: you can't merge them together if you want to queue that Collection ... the actual Collection isn't serialized as it, it only keeps identifiers for the models in the collection, so it needs to be all the same model type so it can then retrieve all those models by id on the queue job side ... on a side note there is a lot of duplicate code here

Comment: @lagbox is there another way i could do this?

Answer (score 0):

well, I did find a way around this. Turning it to an array with `toArray()` like this:

```
 $first = DB::table('nentregas')->join('users as u', 'u.id', 'nentregas.user_id')
            ->select('nentregas.id','nentregas.estado','nentregas.objtype','nentregas.created_at','nentregas.fecha_compra', 'u.name as user')
            ->whereBetween('nentregas.fecha_compra', [$from, $to]);
 $second = DB::table('compras')->join('users as u', 'u.id', 'compras.user_id')
            ->select('compras.id','compras.estado','compras.objtype','compras.created_at','compras.fecha_compra', 'u.name as user') 
            ->whereBetween('compras.fecha_compra', [$from, $to])
            ->union($first)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get()->toArray();

 $this->data = $second; 
 return $this->data;
```